# Can I allow different numbers of cores for different tasks?

Tags: apache-spark

It is said that `spark.executor.cores` / `spark.task.cpus` parameters set the number of cores dedicated for each task's execution. Can I let different tasks have different numbers of cores? If so what denote the flag/parameter? The maximum of cores that can be allocated to a task?

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? I'm having the same issue as my program has some tasks which are single threaded but then one or two which use all the cores on the machine.

Comment: @OliverDain: No, I never looked into the issue in detail. It was a general question and it wasn't essential for my job to be able to solve it. However, I would appreciate it still very much if you post an answer once you find a solution. Even a "can't be done" would be helpful.